# use sleep or update javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am new to javascript and jquery, just finished a tutorial.

```
$('form').keydown(function (key) {
    key = parseInt(key.which, 10);
    var toAdd = $('input[name=type]').val();
    var s = $('.text p').text();
if (key !== 8) {
    s = s.substring(0, toAdd.length);
    alert(s);
    alert(toAdd);
    if (toAdd === s) {
        $('.img').animate({ left: '+=25px' }, 5);
    }
```

this is part of the code im trying to execute.

but when i insert text into the textbox, the first letter is not assigned into toAdd.

when i put the line between second and third line it work's just fine:

```
alert("something");
```

do i need to use a function that wait's a bit or something?

i hope i was understandable..

thank you

Comment: seems weird you are listening to the event on the form and not the input. `$('form').on("keyup", "input[name=type]", function (evt) { console.log(this.value); });`

Comment: just fixed that.. thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use `keyup` and not `keydown`. The letter is not in the textbox yet when keydown is fired.

Comment: Dang, beat me by 5 seconds